# what is oem-sutton.simon-camile-meta, [why] do I need it?

Tags: drivers, 20.04

Installed mint 20.04 on a new thinkbook
had to switch it up to the 5.11 kernel for the display to work properly

anyway, system report says "hardware driver Unknown missing" ... launch driver manager

it says "this driver is not working"  "oem-sutton.simon-camile-meta"

so I can enable it 20.04-ubuntu1 or: 'do not use this device'

1. What is it (googled everywhere, not a single thing says what it is, only where to get it"
2. do I even need it?  (will my cat spontaneously combust without it?)

I know it's likely volunteer contrib, but at least a 1 line description would be nice.

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu Mint.  Ubuntu also has *flavors* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) which does **not** include Mint.  There are Mint themes used by desktops, but Linux Mint is a different OS that is based on Ubuntu, but uses runtime *adjustments* so it can use Ubuntu packages, where as Ubuntu and *flavors* are run-time adjustment free (they can edit the source & create new Ubuntu packages so have no need).  Official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sutton Simon Camille meta package contains hardware configuration files for the Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G2-series notebooks¹. These are provided by Lenovo themselves, occasionally with input from community members who reverse-engineer issues with the default Ubuntu installation on their hardware.

Do you need it? No. Do you want it? Yes.

---

¹ — Other notebook models are likely included, but the G2 is referenced most often.